# PHP spreadsheet not exporting ion server

Tags: php

The PHP spreadsheet is working fine in the localhost. But When I uploaded in to the production server. The following error boots up. I have attached the following browser loading error

```
<?php

session_start();
include "includes/db.php";
require '..\vendor\autoload.php';
 
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;



 if(isset($_POST['export_csv_data'])) 
 { 
    $export     = $_POST['export']; 
    $filename   =  "Adjudication-Sheet";

      $search_query="SELECT * FROM `adjudication_team` WHERE document_reviewed_by = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
      $result=mysqli_query($connection,$search_query);
      if($result)
 {

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'USER ID');
$sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'PATIENT NAME');
$sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'DOCUMENT BY');
$sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'DOCUMENT RECEIVED DATE');
$sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'UHID NUMBER');
$sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'ACTUAL DATE');
$sheet->setCellValue('H1', 'ACTUAL DISCHARGE');
$sheet->setCellValue('I1', 'HOSPITAL BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('J1', 'MAIN BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('K1', 'PHARMACY BILL EXCLUDED');
$sheet->setCellValue('L1', 'ADVANCE PAYMENT');
$sheet->setCellValue('M1', 'PHARMACY BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('N1', 'PRE HOSPITALIZATION');
$sheet->setCellValue('O1', 'POST HOSPITALIZATION');
$sheet->setCellValue('P1', 'OUTSIDE HOSPITALIZATION');
$sheet->setCellValue('Q1', 'TOTAL BILL AMOUNT');
$sheet->setCellValue('R1', 'DOCUMENT REVIEWED DATE');
$sheet->setCellValue('S1', 'DOCUMENT REVIEWED BY');
$sheet->setCellValue('T1', 'HOSPITAL PAID RECIEPT');
$sheet->setCellValue('U1', 'INVESTIGATION BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('V1', 'PRE HOSPITALIZATION BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('W1', 'POST HOSPITALIZATION BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('X1', 'OUTSIDE HOSPITALIZATION BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('Y1', 'INVESTIGATION BILL');
$sheet->setCellValue('Z1', 'DATE IN');

$rowcount = 2;
foreach($result as $row)
{
$sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowcount,$row['id']);
$sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowcount,$row['user_id']);
$sheet->setCellValue('C'.$rowcount,$row['patient_name']);
$sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rowcount,$row['document_by']);
$sheet->setCellValue('E'.$rowcount,$row['document_received_date']);
$sheet->setCellValue('F'.$rowcount,$row['uhid_number']);
$sheet->setCellValue('G'.$rowcount,$row['actual_date']);
$sheet->setCellValue('H'.$rowcount,$row['actual_discharge']);
$sheet->setCellValue('I'.$rowcount,$row['hospital_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('J'.$rowcount,$row['main_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('K'.$rowcount,$row['pharmacy_bill_excluded']);
$sheet->setCellValue('L'.$rowcount,$row['advance_payment']);
$sheet->setCellValue('M'.$rowcount,$row['pharmacy_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('N'.$rowcount,$row['pre_hospitalization']);
$sheet->setCellValue('O'.$rowcount,$row['post_hospitalization']);
$sheet->setCellValue('P'.$rowcount,$row['outside_hospitalization']);
$sheet->setCellValue('Q'.$rowcount,$row['total_bill_amount']);
$sheet->setCellValue('R'.$rowcount,$row['document_reviewed_date']);
$sheet->setCellValue('S'.$rowcount,$row['document_reviewed_by']);
$sheet->setCellValue('T'.$rowcount,$row['hospital_paid_reciept']);
$sheet->setCellValue('U'.$rowcount,$row['investigation_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('V'.$rowcount,$row['pre_hospitalisation_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('W'.$rowcount,$row['post_hospitalisation_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('X'.$rowcount,$row['outside_hospitalisation_bill']);
$sheet->setCellValue('Y'.$rowcount,$row['discharge_summary']);
$sheet->setCellValue('Z'.$rowcount,$row['date_in']);
$rowcount++;
}

if($export == 'csv')
{
$writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
$final_filename = $filename.'.csv';

}

header('Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.urlencode($final_filename).'"');
$writer->save('php://output');

// $writer->save($final_filename);
}
else
{
 print_r(mysqli_error($connection));
}
  }

 
?>
```

The PHP spreadsheet is working fine in the local host. But When I uploaded it to the production server. The following error boots up. I have attached the following browser loading error
I have attached the code in the above text.

[image: 1]

Comment: at start, check httpd logs, write permissions for httpd user to that location

Comment: Hi Man, Can u just elaborate the comment or share me any reference..